# How to initialize a simple matrix in SAS?

Tags: matrix, sas

I am new to SAS and have been using R most of the time. I am stuck with a simple and frustrating issue. All I want to do is to create a simple 3 X 3 matrix in SAS. But it throws an error. I need some help in understanding what's going on. The SAS documentation is not very helpful.

```
data matrixTest;
 input Y $ X;
 cards;
 4 0
 3 1
 1 1
 ;
run;

/*Convert X to a categorical variable*/
data matrixTest;
set matrixTest;
if X = 0 then X = "0";
else X = "1";
run;

/*Get design matrix from the regression model*/
 proc transreg data=matrixTest design;
  model class(X/ zero=last);
  output out=input_mcmc(drop=_: Int:);
 run;



mX = {5 4 3, 4 0 4, 7 10 3};
```

And I get the following error when creating the matrix mX:

```
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error is that SAS is not a matrix language.  SAS is more like a database language; the unit of operation is the dataset, analogous to a SQL table or a dataframe in R or Python.

SAS does have a matrix language built into the system, SAS/IML (interactive matrix language), but it's not part of base SAS and isn't really what you use in the context you're showing.  The way you enter data as part of your program is how you did it in the first data step, with datalines.

Side note: You're also showing some R tendencies in the second data step; you cannot convert a variable's type that way.  SAS has only 'numeric' and 'character', so you don't have 'categorical' data type anyway; just leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use the same data set name in the SET and DATA statements. This makes it hard to debug because you've destroyed your initial data set.
2. You cannot change types on the fly in SAS. If a variables i character it stays character.
3. If a variable is numeric, you assign values without quotes, quotes are used for character variables.
4. Your attempt to create a categorical variable doesn't make sense given the fact that it's already 0/1. Make sure your test data is reflective of your actual situation.

I'm not familiar with PROC TRANSREG so I cannot comment on that portion but those are the issues you're facing now.

As someone else mentioned, SAS is not a matrix language, it processes data line by line instead which means it can handle really, really large data sets because it doesn't have to load it into memory.

Your data set, matrixTest is essentially a data set and ready to go. You don't need to convert it to a matrix or 'initialize' it.

If you want a data set with those values then create that as a data set:

```
data mx;
input var1-var3;
cards;
5 4 3
4 0 4
7 10 3
;
run;
```